# $z\in \mathbb{C}$ then $z^k=z$ implies $z=0$ or a root of unity.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am wondering about this statement made in a claim of a proof. Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k\ge 2\in \mathbb{N}$. Then if $z^k=z$  either $z=0$ or $z$ is a $(k-1)$th root of unity. I understand why $z^{k-1}$ would be a root of unity but why is it that we know that it might be either $z=0$ or a root of unity and not potentially something else? I could see this being only a k th root of unity since $z^k=z \iff z^{k-1}=1$ and if $z$ were zero here then I would get $0=1$ which is a contradiction. How do I know that one of those two cases must hold?

Thank you!

Comment: $z=0$ is a root for sure. Now suppose that $z\neq 0$. Thus, we can divide through by $z$ to get $z^{k-1}=1$. You can see now that $z$ must be a $(k-1)$th root of unity. Alternatively, write your equation as $z(z^{k - 1}  - 1) = 0$. Now the left-hand side can only be zero if one of the factors $z$ or $z^{k-1}-1$ is zero. Can you conclude?

Comment: What do you mean by “I undestand why $z^{k-1}$ would be a root of unity…” when you immediately contradict that statement, showing you don’t understand? $z^{k-1}$ is either $0$ or $1,$ so when $z\neq0,$ $z^{k-1}$ is a very trivial root of unity.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for putting it this way it was so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z\ne 0$ then you can divide by it and obtain $z^{k-1}=1$. This by definition says that in this case $z$ is a $(k-1)$-th root of unity.